# Java regexp error: \( is not a valid character

Tags: java, regex

I was using java regexp today and found that you are not allowed to use the following regexp sequence

```
String pattern = "[a-zA-Z\\s\\.-\\)\\(]*";
```

if I do use it it will fail and tell me that \( is not a valid character.

But if I change the regexp to

```
String pattern = "[[a-zA-Z\\s\\.-]|[\\(\\)]]*";
```

Then it will work. Is this a bug in the regxp engine or am I not understanding how to work with the engine?

*EDIT:* I've had an error in my string: there shouldnt be 2 starting [[, it should be only one. This is now corrected

Comment: When you have a problem with a well-established library, don't assume that it has a bug right away. More likely than not, the library is behaving correctly.

Comment: You are correct, I shouldn't have assumed it was a bugg but rather error phrone code by me. Thx for the help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your regex has two problems.

1. You've not closed the character class.
2. The `-` is acting as a range operator with `.` on LHS and `(` on RHS. But `(` comes before `.` in unicode, so this results in an invalid range.

To fix problem 1, close the char class or if you meant to not include `[` in the allowed characters delete one of the `[`.

To fix problem 2, either escape the `-` as `\\-` or move the `-` to the beginning or to the end of the char class.

So you can use:

```
String pattern = "[a-zA-Z\\s\\.\\-\\)\\(]*";
```

or

```
String pattern = "[a-zA-Z\\s\\.\\)\\(-]*";
```

or

```
String pattern = "[-a-zA-Z\\s\\.\\)\\(]*";
```

Comment: none of the three is a valid regex and causes `Unclosed character class` exception

Comment: @tulskiy: Was editing the answer while you commented. And yes you are right.

Comment: Moving the "-" sign to the beginning made it work. I accedantly pasted an extra [ in the begining. Thx!

Comment: How would the last pattern work? The dash should be inside the character class.

Answer (score 5):

You should only use the dash `-` at the end of the character class, since it is normally used to show a range (as in `a-z`). Rearrange it:

```
String pattern = "[[a-zA-Z\\s\\.\\)\\(-]*";
```

Also, I don't think you have to escape `(.)` characters inside brackets.

**Update**: As others pointed out, you must also escape the `[` in a java regex character class.

Comment: Agreed, also I am not sure if op thinks "\\s" will be interpreted as "space character" (which it will not). I think this may be a misunderstanding of character classes and would recommended reading through: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: *"Also, I don't think you have to escape (.) characters inside brackets."*. - No, you definitely don't have to do this.

Comment: @Tim: The answer is still incorrect. Read other answers to know why.

Comment: @codaddict: Why? It should be fine not to escape `[`.

Comment: @Tim: It works fine in Perl, PHP but not in Java. Try it and see.

Comment: @Tim: no, you can have nested character classes, so the square bracket has to me matched.

Comment: @tulskiy: I was wondering when one would ever want to nest character classes, and found that java support things like character class intersections. Thanks.

Comment: Iv edited my question, in my original pattern, there was an extra [ in the begining, that was not intentional. It has now been updated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `\.-\)` (`"\\.-\\)"` in a Java string literal) tries to define a range from `.` to `)`. Since the Unicode codepoint of `.` (U+002E) is higher than that of `)` (U+0029) this is an error.

Try using this pattern and you'll see: `[z-a]`.

The correct solution is to either put the dash `-` at the end of the character group (at which point it will lose its special meaning) or to escape it.

You also need to close the unclosed open square bracket or escape it, if it was not intended for grouping.

Also, escaping the fullstop `.` is not necessary inside a character group.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the dash and close the unmatched square bracket. So you are going to get two errors with this regex:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index 14
```

because the dash is used to specify a range, and \) is obviously a not valid range character. If you escape the dash, making it `[[a-zA-Z\s\.\-\)\(]*` you'll get

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 19
```

which means that you have an extra opening square bracket that is used to specify character class. I don't know what you meant by putting an extra bracket here, but either escaping or removing it will make it a valid regex.

Comment: the extra [ was a mistake by me when copying the code. This should not be included at all.